# Laravel JWT : generated tokens on the localhost are valid on the server

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I am writing an API for a mobile app, the backend website is written in Laravel. I'm using Tymon\JWTAuth for authentication like this:

```
function  auth()
{
    try {
        if(!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate())
        {
            return  ('login or register');
        }
    }
    catch (JWTException $e )
    {
        return   ('token is invalid');
    }
    return  $this->user = $user ;
}
```

today I've noticed something, when I generate a JWT token for a user with id `4` on my localhost API and if I send that same token to a live API instead of getting an error I get the user with id `4`! Basically I can login with any user I want just by generating some token on his/her id on my localhost. Am I missing something?

I don't know if this has anything to do with this, but to save time when testing, I don't send tokens as part of POST body and header, just in the URL with `GET` method  like:

```
site.com/api/user?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
```

Comment: I would make this a comment but I don't have enough reputation. Is your secret key the same in both your local and remote locations? I'm not 100% sure but it may be the case that all possible combinations of a user's JWT token are valid unless explicitly blacklisted (or they are expired). So if you have the same secret key, then you get valid tokens for both apps. I'm new to JWT tokens as well so I'd like to see if someone has more knowledge about this. [See this link for info on how JWT Tokens are verified](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/verify-access-token)

Comment: @LeviJames yep , that was it , pleas post it as answer if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the secret key on your localhost and remote location are the same. Changing these up will likely solve your problem.